# Magnetic Resonance in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, nuclear-magnetic-resonance

Using the identity ($I$) and the Pauli operators ($\sigma_{i}$) as a basis, the Hamiltonian of any two-level system (of basis states $\{|0\rangle,|1\rangle\}$) can be expressed as follows
$$
H =\frac{\hbar}{2}(\alpha \cdot I+\textbf{r}\cdot\boldsymbol{\sigma})=\frac{\hbar}{2}(\alpha \cdot \sigma _{0}+r_{x} \cdot \sigma _{x}+r_{y} \cdot \sigma _{y}+r_{z} \cdot \sigma _{z})=\frac{\hbar}{2}{\begin{pmatrix}\alpha +r_{z} &r_{x} -ir_{y} \\ r_{x} +ir_{y} &\alpha -r_{z} \end{pmatrix}}
$$
for some $\alpha,r_{x},r_{y},r_{z}\in\mathbb{C}$. Using the fact that the time evolution operator is given by ${U}(t)=e^{-\frac{i}{\hbar}{H}t}$, it is supposedly possible (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-state_quantum_system#Time_dependence) to show that

$$U (t)=e^{-i\alpha t/2 }\left(\cos \left({\frac {|\mathbf {r} |}{2 }}t\right)I-i\frac{\hat {r}\cdot {\boldsymbol {\sigma }}}{|\textbf{r}|}\sin \left({\frac {|\mathbf {r} |}{2 }}t\right)\right)$$
Nuclear magnetic resonance is the result of Hamiltonians of the form
$$\alpha=0,\textbf{r}=\begin{pmatrix}\Omega\cos(\omega_{1}t)\\\Omega\sin(\omega_{1}t)\\\omega_{0}\end{pmatrix}$$
Hence if we start in the state $|0\rangle$, the probability of measuring the state $|0\rangle$ at time $t$ is given by
\begin{align*}
P_{0}(t)&=|\langle0|U(t)|0\rangle|^{2}\\&=|U_{00}(t)|^{2}
\end{align*}
We see that
$$|\textbf{r}|=\sqrt{\Omega^{2}+\omega^{2}_{0}}$$
hence
$$P_{0}(t)=\cos^{2}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\Omega^{2}+\omega^{2}_{0}}t}{2}\right)+\frac{\omega_{0}^{2}}{\Omega^{2}+\omega^{2}_{0}}\sin^{2}\left(\frac{\sqrt{\Omega^{2}+\omega^{2}_{0}}t}{2}\right)$$
which is independent of the frequency of radiation, $\omega_{1}$. Is this expression correct? I thought there was supposed to be some kind of dependence on $\omega_{1}$. Many thanks for any help

Comment: The formula you have quoted for $U(t)$ is for the special case in which ${\bf r}$ is constant.

Comment: Why does this formula only apply for constant $\textbf{r}$? If you exponentiate the matrix you should obtain the same result I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct time dependent probability of being in the $|0\rangle$ state at time $t$ is the following:
$$
P_0(t) = \frac{\Omega^2}{\omega_R^2} \sin^2{\frac{\omega_R t}{2}},
$$
where
$$
\omega_R^2 = \Omega^2 + (\omega_0 - \omega_1)^2.
$$
So as you can see there is indeed a dependence on the frequency of the driving field $\omega_1$.

The problem with your approach, as pointed out in the comments by Buzz, is that the time evolution operator $U(t)$ that you use is only valid for time-independent Hamiltonians.
In order to get the result above, you can take advantage of the time-periodicity of the Hamiltonian and you can apply the *Floquet theory*.
In a nutshell, this theory exploits the time periodicity of the Hamiltonian to write an analogue of the Bloch theorem for discrete time translation invariance, which in turn allows a relatively easy calculation of the correct $U(t)$ via an equivalent time-independent problem.

Comment: Ah alright thanks, not sure I understand why the formula only applies for time dependent hamiltonians though

Comment: Well, the time evolution operator comes from the solution of the Schrodinger equation $i\hbar \partial_t\psi(t) = H(t)\psi(t)$. If you substitute $\psi(t) = U(t) \psi_0$ into the Schrodinger equation with the $U(t)$ that you have mentioned, you see that the equation is not satisfied, unless $H(t)$ is time-independent

Comment: ah yeh of course $\hat{U}$ only applied to time independent hamiltonians, thanks